# How to increase height of JSeparator in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, height, jseparator

I'm building an app to record orders and generate invoice for those orders. I use a jSeparator to separate the client info from the order info. But i want to increase the height of the Separator and change its colour also.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have already tried using the setSize() Method but it doesn't work.
I used netbeans drag and drop to design it so the initComponents method sets up all Swing components .

```
public GenInvoice() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    jSeparator1.setSize(this.getWidth(), 4);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513172/set-width-for-jseperator

Comment: Alas separators are not designed to be modified like this, at least in their standard behavior. Customize it as suggested before (for example) or create your own new separator component.

Answer (score -2):

You can use setBounds(); instead of setSize(); and there you will place it too.

Comment: SetBounds() only works when layout is set to null and mine isn't